# Where do I find System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices in .NET CORE 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, system.data

My .NET 4.0 app used the PluralizationServices located in System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices. When I went to convert my app to .NET CORE 5.0, the compiler complains:

> The type or namespace name 'PluralizationService' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've tried using System.Data, and using System.Data.Common.

Where do I find this in .NET 5.0?

Comment: Docs say this is not supported on net core - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice, switch the drop down on the left to net  core - we use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pluralize.NET but not in an EF context

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/2506#issuecomment-121317996

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices` is not available in .NET Core or .NET.

See [the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice) (try switching that page to .NET 5/.NET Core; you cannot) and also [this comment from the devs](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/2506#issuecomment-121317996).

Possible replacements include [PluralizeService.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PluralizeService.Core), [Pluralize.NET](https://github.com/sarathkcm/Pluralize.NET), or [Humanizer](https://humanizr.net/).

Comment: Thanks, I found Pluralize.NET.dll and it works well.